# Add padding top to Cordova statusbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to create a cordova application with translucent statusbar. 
Using the Cordova-plugin-statusbar, I manage to this result. However, the content of the statusbar is overlapping with those native android statusbar content as shown in this image.

[image]

is there any other way to correct this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<plugin spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" source="git" />
```

[phonegap-developers-guid](http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/)

Answer (score 1):

The `cordova-plugin-statusbar` increases the page height to include the area with device status info making your page area start at the top left of the screen instead of under the device status bar. You just need to add top padding to the your status bar area.

HTML:

```
<div id=".statusBar">...Status bar content...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.statusBar{
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Depending on your intended appearance you may also want to use `cordova-plugin-device` to detect any differences in platform status bars too and modify CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `safe-area-inset-top` CSS environment variable:

```
body {
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top) !important;
}
```

If you have fixed elements, you also need similar rules to correct their position.
Ex:

```
.status-bar {
  top: env(safe-area-inset-top) !important;
}
```

More information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env